# Why can't I connect to Minecraft PE servers?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Nexus 7 tablet which I'm using on a solid internet connection. I'm playing Minecraft PE 0.8.1, and it says that you can not connect to the server. Why am I not able to connect?

Comment: Do you mean servers in the Internet? PE can only connect inside a single Wi-Fi network, not over Internet, if I recall correctly. Do you mind saying what Minecraft PE servers are you trying to connect to?

Comment: dare i ask if you are running this server from a computer or not because if you are running it from a computer it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be connected to the same Internet server as your friend. One of you have to be playing the game while the other is choosing their world. It will pop up saying that you can join the other players world. Click on it and you are all set up. You can use the wifi tether on the settings, though you may need to look for more information on how to do this.